# Packages disabled by build tags still linked into binary

Tags: go, build, binary, tags

I use build tags to disable one feature, such as:

### source

- abc_enable.go

```
// +build abc
package main

import (
  "big-package"
  "bigbig"
)
...
```

- abc_disable.go

```
// +build !abc

// empty
```

### build cmd

- enable: `go build --tags abc`
- disable: `go build`

this method works always.

### problem

but I found build binary size keeps big when abc disabled.

- keep abc_enable.go, `--tags abc`. size up to 11M
- keep abc_enable.go, no tags. size up to **11M**
- remove abc_enable.go by hand, size down to **5M**

**is there any link options or build options to fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Build constraints**](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_constraints)

> To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series
> of build constraints **must** be followed by a blank line.

That means that `// +build abc` in your original code snippet is *not* considered a build constraint. To fix this you have to add a blank line above of the package clause.

```golang
// +build abc

package main

import (
  "big-package"
  "bigbig"
)
...
```